# No module named <my_package>.msg and <mocap>.srv

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### **SOLVED  -- UPDATED  14/10/2015**

i've followed this tutorial [in here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv). I finally succesfull known node for my_package. Thankyou all. especially ROS developer ^^)b

---

13/10/2015

Hello there again, after i did success launch again my package with my problem before [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/220832/skeletonlaunch-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-skeleton_markers-nor-is-skeleton_markers-a-launch-file/) . now i got my old problem with python program. I'm not really familiar with python code especially for ROS, so i got confused even after i read [this topic problem](http://answers.ros.org/question/190244/exporting-python-module-with-same-name-as-package-with-srvmsg/) which solved by reference from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/PyStyleGuide#Package.2BAC8-Module_Names_.28__init__.py_files.29). I still got some confused stuff because now i'm catkinized my friends code from ROS electric (i'm using Indigo), so the directory path maybe got some differences:

- i have all my python code in :

  ```
   my_package
    |- bin/
        |- all my code.py
  ```

and i change it to :

```
      my_package
       |- nodes/
           |- all my code.py
```

i don't know is it different or not.. i just got reference it from my another catkin package which including python in folder "nodes". but i read in [here](http://wiki.ros.org/PyStyleGuide#Package.2BAC8-Module_Names_.28__init__.py_files.29). there's folder named "src" and "scripts". am i doing right thing or not?

- in that reference website tutorial, said that `This paragraph is only necessary for packages which use rosbuild/rosmake. If the package is using catkin it must not use roslib.load_manifest.`  so, if i deleted it, is it okay?
- where should i placed my exported python files, if the python code like this :

  ```
   import rospy
   import pi_tracker_lib as PTL
   from my_package.msg import Skeleton
   from mocap.srv import *
   import PyKDL as KDL
   from math import copysign
   import time
  ```

and this is my error in terminal :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/adelleodel/ros/src/my_package/nodes/ZMP_tracker_command.py", line 26, in <module>
     from my_package.msg import Skeleton
    ImportError: No module named my_package.msg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/adelleodel/ros/src/my_package/nodes/ZMP_skelplot2.py", line 47, in <module>
    from mocap.srv import *
    ImportError: No module named mocap.srv
    [tracker_command-1] process has died [pid 5382, exit code 1, cmd /home/adelleodel/ros/src/my_package/nodes/ZMP_tracker_command.py __name:=tracker_command __log:=/home/adelleodel/.ros/log/43be4ef4-8959-11e5-8b17-0185f2817c5b/tracker_command-1.log].
    log file: /home/adelleodel/.ros/log/43be4ef4-8959-11e5-8b17-0185f2817c5b/tracker_command-1*.log
    [ZMP_skelplot-2] process has died [pid 5383, exit code 1, cmd /home/adelleodel/ros/src/my_package/nodes/ZMP_skelplot2.py __name:=ZMP_skelplot __log:=/home/adelleodel/.ros/log/43be4ef4-8959-11e5-8b17-0185f2817c5b/ZMP_skelplot-2.log].
    log file: /home/adelleodel/.ros/log/43be4ef4-8959-11e5-8b17-0185f2817c5b/ZMP_skelplot-2*.log
```

thankyou for the respond :)

---

UPDATED

This is CMakeList.txt:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
    project(my_package)

   find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
   dynamixel_controllers
   dynamixel_driver
   dynamixel_msgs
   geometry_msgs
   joint_state_publisher
   visualization_msgs
   message_generation
   nav_msgs
   openni_tracker
   roscpp
   rospy
   rviz
   std_msgs
   tf
   urdf
   )

  find_package(orocos_kdl REQUIRED)
  find_package(PkgConfig)
  pkg_check_modules(OpenNI REQUIRED libopenni)

  # Find Glut
  find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

  # Find OpenGL
  find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED) 

  link_directories(
      ${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS}
      ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARY_DIRS}
      ${OpenNI_LIBRARIES}
      ${GLUT_LIBRARIES}
      ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    )

   find_library(LIBFREENECT_LIBRARY
      NAMES freenect
      PATHS ${LIBFREENECT_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    )

    catkin_package(
       DEPENDS orocos_kdl
    )

    include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                ${OpenNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                ${orocos_kdl_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    )

    add_executable(skeleton_tracker2 src/skeleton_tracker.cpp src/KinectController.cpp src/KinectDisplay.cpp)

    target_link_libraries(skeleton_tracker2
      ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
      ${OpenNI_LIBRARIES}
      ${GLUT_LIBRARIES}
      ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}  
      ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES}
    )

    message("DEBUG variable catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message("DEBUG variable OpenNI_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${OpenNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message("DEBUG variable GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message("DEBUG variable orocos_kdl_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${orocos_kdl_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

package.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <package>
      <name>my_package</name>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
      <description>The my_package package</description>

      <maintainer email="adelleodel@todo.todo">adelleodel</maintainer>

      <!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 -->
      <license>TODO</license>

      <!-- Url tags are optional, but mutiple are allowed, one per tag -->
      <!-- Optional attribute type can be: website, bugtracker, or repository -->
      <!-- Example: -->
      <!-- <url type="website">http://wiki.ros.org/skripsi_mocap</url> -->

      <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
      <build_depend>dynamixel_controllers</build_depend>
      <build_depend>dynamixel_driver</build_depend>
      <build_depend>dynamixel_msgs</build_depend>
      <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
      <build_depend>joint_state_publisher</build_depend>
      <build_depend>orocos_kdl</build_depend>
      <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
      <build_depend>libopenni2-dev</build_depend>
      <build_depend>libusb-1.0-dev</build_depend>
      <build_depend>libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev</build_depend>
      <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
      <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
      <build_depend>rviz</build_depend>
      <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
      <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
      <build_depend>urdf</build_depend>
      <build_depend>nite</build_depend>
      <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
      <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
      <run_depend>dynamixel_controllers</run_depend>
      <run_depend>dynamixel_driver</run_depend>
      <run_depend>dynamixel_msgs</run_depend>
      <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
      <run_depend>joint_state_publisher</run_depend>
      <run_depend>orocos_kdl</run_depend>
      <run_depend>nav_msgs</run_depend>
      <run_depend>libopenni2-dev</run_depend>
      <run_depend>libusb-1.0-dev</run_depend>
      <run_depend>libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev</run_depend>
      <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
      <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
      <run_depend>rviz</run_depend>
      <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
      <run_depend>tf</run_depend>
      <run_depend>urdf</run_depend>
      <run_depend>nite</run_depend>

      <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags --> 
      <export>
        <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

      </export>
    </package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220869/no-module-named-%3Cmy_package%3E.msg-and-%3Cmocap%3E.srv/) by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-11-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-11-13**:
You don't find the respective modules, which points to misconfigured `CMakeLists.txt`  and `package.xml`. Please post those as well by updating your question above or provide a link to an Online Repo where we can find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### **UPDATED**

i've solved my problem. the problem is that mocap.srv is not find because i don't have package named 'mocap' (this is my friends project before, using electric ROS. and now i'm re-new it with ROS Indigo. so, i just copying main package of him. mocap is one of package in his workspace). and now i just move the file named ***.srv to my srv directory, and change my python code from `from mocap.srv import *` to `from my_package.srv import *`

i've read ROS tutorial over and over again. Thankyou ROS developer!!

---

Originally posted by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) with karma: 76 on 2015-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0